# Circular Images in cards, class added but no change

Tags: css, materialize

i'm trying to make a website that display a team, each member inside a card, but the project need the profile photo to be a circle, i've tried to add the class "circle" to the image but it doenst work...

checklist of what i've tried:
- adding circle class to the img - No Sucess 
- adding a custom Style with border-radius 50%; - No Sucess 
- adding circle class to the card-image div - No Sucess

my code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 l4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <img src="images/marcelo.jpg" alt="Foto do Fundador da Empresa,Marcelo Borges Fagundes" >
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title">Marcelo Borges Fagundes</span>
                    <p>Fundador da Empresa</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 l4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="images/thiago.jpg" alt="Foto do Funcionario da empresa,Thiago Zaleski Leon"  class="circle">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Thiago Zaleski</span>
                        <p>Auxiliar de Informática</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

The card still show as a rectangular image :(
any ideias how to outcome this?

Comment: Can you please include the CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.card-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 l4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="Foto do Fundador da Empresa,Marcelo Borges Fagundes" >
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title">Marcelo Borges Fagundes</span>
                    <p>Fundador da Empresa</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 l4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="Foto do Funcionario da empresa,Thiago Zaleski Leon"  class="circle">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <span class="card-title">Thiago Zaleski</span>
                        <p>Auxiliar de Informática</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a "crop" div, which makes the image circular, without ruining the resolution, with `overflow: hidden`.

```css
.crop {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/fb/8a/8d/fb8a8defbf55501ce344e161f8c44fed--google-images-gift-ideas.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7u328wf9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your card-image class:

```
.card-image{
  clip-path: circle(100px at center);
}
```

what will happen is it will clip the image from center by making a circle with radius of 100px you can change the pixel to fit you image size

Answer (score -1):

To create circles you can apply `border-radius: 100%;`

```css
img {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 l4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="https://dhirajkumarsingh.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/css3-html5-logo.png" alt="Foto do Fundador da Empresa,Marcelo Borges Fagundes" class="circle">
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">Marcelo Borges Fagundes</span>
        <p>Fundador da Empresa</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col s12 l4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3d/CSS.3.svg/730px-CSS.3.svg.png" alt="Foto do Funcionario da empresa,Thiago Zaleski Leon" class="circle">
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title">Thiago Zaleski</span>
        <p>Auxiliar de Informática</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```